# Deploying from github through Heroku API

Tags: heroku, github, heroku-api

**Background**: I have a project deployed to heroku.  The heroku app is connected with github so I can press the "deploy" button from heroku's web api to manually deploy a branch on github to heroku.

What I'm trying to do is build a slack bot that will let me accomplish that via a slack command.  Ideally, there'd be some function on heroku's [platform api](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/platform-api) like `.deploy('my_app', 'some_branch_on_github)`, but I can't seem to find it.

The platform api's [build](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#build) feature is *close*.  That function lets you provide the public url of a tarball that heroku will then deploy.  However, my github repo isn't public, so that doesn't work.  A private repo *shouldn't* be a problem, though, since heroku's already connected to my github repo.

**TLDR**: How can I programmatically tell Heroku to deploy my app from a private github it's connected to?

Answer (score 11):

I got a response from Heroku's support team asking pretty much the same question.  Their answer was that what I'm trying to do is not possible, but will be at some point (although not in the next few months, anyway).

They suggested that I could just use the undocumented web api used by heroku's own web console (a POST to an endpoint on `kolkrabbi.heroku.com`).  They *did* warn that, as a private api, that's likely to change without warning.

Comment: Could that be any more vague of a name btw? `kolkrabbi.heroku.com` i saw it in my github webhook list and google lead me here. thanks for clearing it up

Comment: Yeah, it probably matches some internal naming scheme for their hosts, since it's not meant to be public facing.

Comment: Kolbrakki is an icelandic word and means Octopus, which is I believe Github's mascot :)

Answer (score 0):

As of [April 2020](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration), Heroku has integrated GitHub natively without recourse to any janky [undocumented Icelandic endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428419/deploying-from-github-through-heroku-api#:%7E:text=Kolbrakki%20is%20an,at%2013%3A44).

When configured, Heroku can automatically build and release (if the build is successful) pushes to the specified GitHub repo.

### Enabling GitHub integration

You can configure GitHub integration in the **`Deploy`** tab of apps in
the [Heroku Dashboard](https://dashboard.heroku.com/).

[image: Enable GitHub integration]

To configure GitHub integration, you have to authenticate with GitHub.
You only have to do this once per Heroku account.

GitHub repo admin access is required for you to configure automatic
GitHub deploys. This is because Heroku has to register a service hook on
the GitHub repo, and this action requires admin access. For GitHub
organizations, your GitHub account will also need to be a member of the
organization and not an outside collaborator.

If your repo is in a GitHub organization that has [third-party
application restrictions
enabled](https://help.github.com/articles/about-third-party-application-restrictions/),
an organization admin needs to approve Heroku for use with the
organization. More details are [available on
GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/about-third-party-application-restrictions/).

After you link your Heroku app to a GitHub repo, you can selectively
deploy from branches or configure auto-deploys.

### Manual deploys

With manual deploys, you can create an immediate deployment of any
branch from the GitHub repo that’s connected to your app. Use manual
deploys if you want to control when changes are deployed to Heroku.

[image: Manual deploy]

You can also use manual deploys to temporarily deploy a branch other
than the one that’s configured for automatic deployment. For example,
you might have a development app synced to the `development` GitHub
branch, but you temporarily want to test a feature branch. Simply
trigger a manual deploy of the feature branch to test it on the Heroku
app. Note that release of the feature branch is overwritten on the next
successful GitHub push to the `development` branch.

### Automatic deploys

When you enable automatic deploys for a GitHub branch, Heroku builds and
deploys all pushes to that branch. If, for example, you have a
development app on Heroku, you can configure pushes to your GitHub
`development` branch to be automatically built and deployed to that app.

[image: Automatic deploys]

If you’ve configured your GitHub repo to use automated Continuous
Integration (with Travis CI, for example), you can check the “Wait for
CI to pass before deploy” checkbox. When enabled, Heroku will only
auto-deploy after all the commit statuses of the relevant commit show
`success`.

This commit won’t auto-deploy because one of the checks shows a
`pending` status: [image: Failed commit status - won't auto-deploy]

This commit will auto-deploy because all of the checks show a status of
`success`: [image: Success commit statuses - will auto-deploy]

### Review apps

With review apps enabled for a Heroku app, Heroku will create temporary
test apps for each pull request that’s opened on the GitHub repo that’s
connected to the parent app. Review apps are great if you’re using
[GitHub Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) to propose,
discuss, and merge changes to your code base. Because pull request
branches are deployed to new apps on Heroku, it’s very simple for you
and your collaborators to test and debug code branches. You can also run
automated integration tests on the Heroku app representing a GitHub
branch.

See the [Review apps
article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps)
for details.

### Heroku CI

Once you’ve connected your GitHub repo to your Pipeline, you can turn on
[Heroku CI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci), our
visual, low-configuration test runner that integrates easily with Heroku
Pipelines (and so complements Review apps, existing Heroku apps, and our
GitHub integrations). Any Heroku Pipeline is already Heroku CI ready –
just turn it on in the Pipeline’s **`Settings`** tab.

### Links to diffs

For apps that are linked to GitHub repos, releases in the Dashboard
**`Activity`** tab will include a “View Diff” link. Following the link
will take you to the GitHub comparison view, showing the changes made
since the last release.

[image: Diff view link]

### Disconnecting from GitHub

Terminate an obsolete GitHub connection, if necessary.

#### Disconnecting individual apps

Individual apps can be disconnected in the GitHub pane of the
**`Deploy`** tab for the app.

[image: Screenshot of UI to disconnect app]

#### Disconnecting account

You can disconnect your Heroku and GitHub accounts in the [Applications
pane on your Dashboard account
page](https://dashboard.heroku.com/account/applications#third-party-applications).

[image: Screenshot of UI to disconnect accounts]